# Proper navbar items (image with text under it) positioning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to make bootstrap navbar (responsive) where items will be some images with proper word(or two) under that image:

```
ul class="nav navbar-nav ribonItemList">

<li>
    <a class="ribonItem" data-ajax="true" href="/Home/ChangeWeek?command=Previous">
        <img class="img-rounded ribonImage" id="ribonImg" src="/Images/weekprevious.gif" />
        Previous Week
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a class="ribonItem" data-ajax="true" href="/Home/ChangeWeek?command=Current">
        <img class="img-rounded ribonImage" id="ribonImg" src="/Images/week.gif" />
        Current Week
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a class="ribonItem" data-ajax="true" href="/Home/ChangeWeek?command=Next">
        <img class="img-rounded ribonImage" id="ribonImg" src="/Images/weeknext.gif" />
        Next Week
    </a>
</li>
```

As a result I got:

[image]

How to format it to get valid, responsive layout?

Comment: Can you modify the HTML? If you can, wrap the text in a `div` or a `span` with `display:block`, and that should do the trick

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yes, that does merge words, but on "xs" it doesn't look good, text and images are seperated and not close to one another

Comment: Ok. Could you include the related CSS into the question?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro This is generally how it looks: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMMwBx